# How do I get text value for span that is populated with KO?

Tags: jquery, knockoutjs, knockout

inside a js file I need to get the value for

```
 $('.modal-custom.opc-sidebar.opc-summary-wrapper.custom-slide span.cart-price span.price').text()
```

The probles is that span.cart-price span.price is populated using knockout, and $('.modal-custom.opc-sidebar.opc-summary-wrapper.custom-slide span.cart-price span.price').text() returns empty value.

$('.modal-custom.opc-sidebar.opc-summary-wrapper.custom-slide').text()
returns only the title of the cart, the list of products and total cost is added with KO.

```
<!--ko-->
 <span class="price" data-bind="text: getFormattedPrice(getRowDisplayPriceInclTax($parents[2]))">750,10&nbsp;LEI</span>   
 <!--/ko-->
```

this is the content of the file

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (targetFunction) {
        targetFunction.getObservableFields = function () {
            var self = this,
                observableFields = [];

            $.each(self.getRules(), function (carrier, fields) {
                $.each(fields, function (field) {
                    if (observableFields.indexOf(field) === -1) {
                        observableFields.push(field);
                    }
                });
            });

            console.log($('span.price').text());

            observableFields.push('city_id'); // Load shipping method on City_id changed
            observableFields.push('city'); // Load shipping method on City changed

            return observableFields;
        };

        return targetFunction;
    };
});
```

Comment: how about a simple `$('span.price').text()` ?

Comment: $('span.price').text() returns empty value (this must be because the price is loaded with KO)

Comment: can you post your whole code on getting the span text

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code

Comment: How come you are trying to get the value in jQuery rather than Knockout? It seems an odd choice to access a value rendered via KO in jQuery when you could instead just access it via KO.

Comment: because I have to make this test:if ($valuePackage < $valueFreeShipping) {
observableFields.push('city_id'); // Load shipping method on City_id changed
}